# Unable to publish my application to WAS 7.0.0.29 on RAD 7.5.5.5 iFix1

Tags: java, websphere-7, ibm-rad

I'm trying to publish my application to WAS 7.0.0.29, but facing the below issue.

**Environment details are below:**

Operating System: Windows 7
RAD Version: 7.5.5.5 iFix1
WAS Version: 7.0.0.29

**Error Details:**

```
00000018 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_59175917_15.04.14_12.14.50.5172426886460813428056.txt com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.performTask 363
00000018 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_59175917_15.04.14_12.14.50.5481471140400342152325.txt com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run 307


00000018 **SystemErr     R java.lang.NullPointerException**
00000018 SystemErr     R    at **com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.getMDFromModuleRef(ConfigureTask.java:1450)**
00000018 **SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.createMDsIfNeeded(ConfigureTask.java:1410)**
00000018 **SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.reconcileModuleDeployment(ConfigureTask.java:1318)**
00000018 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.performTask(ConfigureTask.java:309)
00000018 **SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:294**)
00000018 **SystemErr     R  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:738)**
```

Please suggest ways / ideas / workarounds to proceed / resolve this issue.

Comment: All I can understand from this is "...something is null". You need to check what is that your server is not finding. Your app server is got to have other log files which you can check.

Comment: Check what is in these ffdc logs mentioned. Looks like something might be wrong with descriptors in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got the solution, in my deployment.xml file for some of the modules uri was missing.